# RxSwift filter Variable array

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, rx-swift

Hi I am trying to get an understanding of the RxSwift library to write better, functional code.

Currently I am stuck at a very basic problem. Lets say I got this variables of type `Variable<[CiteModel?]>`:

```
var allCites: Variable<[CiteModel?]> = Variable([])
var shownCites: Variable<[CiteModel?]> = Variable([])
```

Now I want to filter all cites from `allCites` array which contain a specific text and add them to `shownCites`.

This is what I have tried but it does not compile because inside my filter block `$0` is `[CiteModel?]` **not** `CiteModel?` what I would expect. Could you explain to me what I did wrong ?

```
private func filterCitesByQuery(query: String) {
    self.shownCites = self.allCites.asObservable().filter {
        $0?.cite.containsString(query)
    }
}
```

**Error** when executing the above code:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'Observable<[CiteModel?]>' (aka 'Observable<Array<Optional<CiteModel>>>') to type 'Variable<[CiteModel?]>' (aka 'Variable<Array<Optional<CiteModel>>>')
```

Comment: Where is this information coming from ? I couldn't find any documentation on the Variable class.

Comment: Yes I updated the question with the error I am currently getting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`map` performs an operation on each values of a **sequence**. When applying `map` to an `Observable<T>`, `map` will receive `T` as a parameter to its block.

In the case of `Variable<[CiteModel?]>`, `Observable` is the **sequence** hence `T == [CiteModel?]`.

Because we really want to filter an array of `[CiteModel?]`, you could change the definition of `filterCitesByQuery` to

```
private func filterCitesByQuery(query: String) {
    // bag probably needs to be reset here
    allCites.asObservable()
        .map { // map: apply a transformation to $0
        // The desired transformation of $0 is to remove cite that do not contain query 
        $0.filter { $0.cite.containsString(query) }
    }
    .bindTo(shownCites)
    .addDisposableTo(bag)
}
```

But this snippet is still sub-optimal, as it requires a subscription to `allCites` to be made, where we don't really want to observe its changes.

A better implementation would be

```
var allCites: Variable<[CiteModel?]> = Variable([])
var searchQuery: Variable<String> = Variable("")
var shownCites: Observable<[CiteModel?]> = Observable .combineLatest(allCites.asObservable(), searchQuery.asObservable()) {
    allCites, query in
    return allCites.map { cites in cites.filter { $0.cite.containsString(query) } }
}

private func filterCitesByQuery(query: String) {
    searchQuery.value = query
}
```

What's going on here ?

`combineLatest` takes the last 2 known values of `allCites` and `searchQuery`. When either of those changes, the block is executed. We now can subscribe to `shownCites` and will get updated values everytime either of the source observable changes.

Comment: Wow what a superb answer. This makes it a lot more clear and to me it looks like the right way to do it, therefore I'll mark this one as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I got it working with this code:

```
private func filterCitesByQuery(query: String) {
     self.shownCites.value = self.allCites.value.filter {
         return $0?.cite.containsString(query) ?? false
     }
 }
```

However i still would like to know which was wrong with original code. So if anyone has an answer for me this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Cannot assign to property: 'value' is a get-only property

Answer (score 1):

```
    //transform Variable to Observable
    allCites.asObservable()
        // Observable<[CiteModel?]> -> Observable<CiteModel?>
        .flatMap { $0.toObservable() }
        // $0?.containsString("query") is Optional, so I have to add ?? false.
        .filter { $0?.containsString("query") ?? false }
        // Observable<CiteModel?> -> Observable<[CiteModel?]>
        .toArray()
        // use bind (a.k.a. subscribe. Don't use .value of Variable)
        .bindTo(shownCites)
        .addDisposableTo(bag)
```

This code should do it for you :)

Comment: Thank you very much much more RxSwift-like than my version I guess.

Comment: hello, i got error warning in allCites.asObservable()